# Does the telegram Location object have a timestamp?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Assume that my bot receives a message from the user which is a Location object,
does the Location have a timestamp? to when was the location captured? (not the msg)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, looking at the [Location object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#location), there does not seem to be a field that hold the time the location was captured.

---

For live-locations, there is a field which indicated the time relative to the message sending the first location:

> **Field**: `live_period`
> **Type** : Integer
> **Description**: *Optional*. Time relative to the message sending date, during which the location can be updated; in seconds. For active live locations only.